# mysql replace last character if match

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `media` with a column called `accounts_used` in which the rows appear in the following format

```
68146, 67342, 60577, 61506, 67194, 67034, 63484, 49113, 61518, 66971, 67511, 
67351, 63621, 67725, 63638, 68141, 66114, 67262, 67537, 67537, 61765, 63701, 
67087, 62641, 61294, 67063, 67049, 67038, 67170, 67147, 67289, 61264, 67091, 
63690, 63505, 63505, 49172, 52313, 67070, 66945, 67234, 62265, 61368, 67870, 
67211, 67586, 49240, 67538, 67538, 67809, 67183, 67164, 62712, 67519, 66895, 
67693, 60266, 60266, 67593, 67031, 67137, 62570, 60682, 61195, 67569, 67569, 
67069, 62082, 67345, 61748, 61553, 52029, 66877, 62630, 67196, 67196, 67196, 
67196, 67196, 67196, 66873, 63677, 68174, 67127, 63594, 67107, 60419, 66601, 
68156, 67203, 68161, 60233, 66586, 52654, 63570, 66887, 67191, 60877, 52108, 
67131, 61784, 67566, 67162, 67073, 67092, 67064, 60133, 66907, 67559, 66846, 
60490, 60347, 66558, 48737, 61539, 67236, 68135, 67238 , 63656, 67585, 67512
```

If the row has a comma at the end I want to remove this, so for example if the row looks like the following

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,
```

I want to replace it to just this

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Is this possible to do using just a simple query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bad idea to store lists of ids in rows.  But, you are doing it.  You can fix this by doing:

```
update media
    set accounts_used = left(accounts_used, length(accounts_used) - 1)
    where accounts_used = '%,';
```

Instead, you should have a `MediaAccounts` table, with one row per "media" and one row per account.

EDIT:

Possibly, the row ends with a `', '` rather than just a comma:

```
update media
    set accounts_used = left(accounts_used, length(accounts_used) - 2)
    where accounts_used = '%, ';
```

Comment: That executed but stated that **0** rows where affected? any reason why?

Comment: Didn't work for me neither. You've to change the last line from "where accounts_used = '%,';" into "where accounts_used LIKE '%,';"

Answer (score 0):

We faced a similar string-replacement issue with a large dataset of bibliographic entries, where we also needed to trim extraneous punctuation from a large number of strings stored in the database which had been imported verbatim from another system. Many of the records in our dataset also contained Unicode characters, as such we needed to find a suitable SQL query that would allow us to find the relevant records that needed to be updated, and then to update them in a way that was Unicode (multibyte character) compatible under MySQL.

In testing with our dataset, I found performing a search for the relevant records we needed to update using MySQL's `LEFT()` and `RIGHT()` substring methods, performed better than using a `LIKE` pattern-match query. Additionally, MySQL's `LENGTH()` method returns the number of bytes in a string, rather than the number of characters, and the distinction is important when dealing with string fields that potentially contain multibyte character sequences as MySQL's substring methods operate on the number of characters to select, rather than the number of bytes. Thus using the `LENGTH()` method did not work in our case where many of strings under test contained multibyte characters. These requirements resulted in an `UPDATE` query with the format presented below:

```
UPDATE media
SET accounts_used = LEFT(accounts_used, CHAR_LENGTH(accounts_used) - 1)
WHERE RIGHT(accounts_used, 1) = ',';
```

The query selects records in the `media` table where the `accounts_used` column ends with a comma `,` (found here using the `WHERE RIGHT(accounts_used, 1) = ','` clause to perform the filtering where the `RIGHT()` method returns a substring of specified length starting on the right of the provided string/column), and then uses the `LEFT(accounts_used, CHAR_LENGTH(accounts_used) - 1)` method call to perform the string trim operation, here trimming the last character from the `accounts_used` column value, where `LEFT()` returns a substring of specified length starting on the left of the provided string/column).

Here the use of the multibyte-aware `CHAR_LENGTH()` method – rather than the basic `LENGTH()` method – was important in our case due to the countless records in our dataset that contained multibyte characters. If you are only dealing with an ASCII-encoded or another single-byte encoded character set then the `LENGTH()` method would work perfectly, and indeed in that case `CHAR_LENGTH()` and `LENGTH()` would return the same length count, and could even be used interchangeably. When dealing with data that could contain multibyte characters, or if in doubt use the `CHAR_LEGNTH()` method instead as it will return an accurate character length count in either case.

*Please note that the column and field names used in the example query above match those noted in the original question, and should be modified as needed to suit your own dataset needs.*